# Laravel Queue:work is consuming all my RAM

Tags: laravel

I am experiencing an issue with Laravel 5.4 and I am hoping that someone can help. I have a laravel 5.4 project where I send emails using queue and execute various commands like below:

```
1. Kernel.php

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();

    $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();

    // Execute command at midnight daily to reject expired applications
    $schedule->command('application:reject')->daily();
}
```

2. In /etc/crontab, I have got the following:

`* * * * * bob cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/oap/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * bob cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/ims/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

When I view my linux system monitor, I notice that every minute, a new php process is started and takes 13.8MB of memory. In about an hour I begin to see my free memory very low. The processes are `/opt/lampp/bin/php-7.1.4 artisan queue:work` and `/usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run`

When the above happens, I would run `artisan queue:restart` and all the php processes would be killed.

What can be the cause of this?

This is weird to me because I have this same code in Laravel 5.1 and I am not experiencing this. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: check with: `ps -ax | grep artisan` if there are many processes, if Yes so use supervisor https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: Hi @num8er. There are many processes.

Comment: ok, I'm writing answer now.

Comment: Here's the simple answer. Never run queue worker in a cron. Create a setup to run a single worker or multiple workers when you start the server. Make sure they respawn if they die, if not your queues won't get processed. So to simplify all this for you there's `Supervisor`.

Comment: Hi @Sandeesh. Thanks for your input. I am in the process of configuring a supervisor

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Sandeesh. It works with a supervisor.

Comment: @FokwaBest no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue worker is a daemon which will keep polling. Stop running queue workers using cron. They're long-lived processes and you run workers based on your requirements from your server, not spawning a new worker every minute.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Read the documentation. If you're not too familiar then just install `Supervisor` and let it handle all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that You're scheduling some command in code.

Some kind of scheduling inside the code that being scheduled every minute. (:

In 5.1 it was working because of there were 2 commands: `queue:listen` that was living long and `queue:work` that was working until queue is empty.

Seems like laravel team going to remove `queue:listen`

So here is solution:

1) Just remove Your code from `Kernel.php` and schedule it as normal artisan call:

```
# daily
0 0 * * * bob cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/ims/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan application:reject >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

2) Run manually or supervise `queue:work` with supervisor:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/oap/ && nohup php artisan queue:work &
```

Comment: Read the documentation that's linked in my answer. The `queue:work` command spawns a worker that's a long lived process. Even if he changes the schedule to daily, he'd have 60 workers by the end of 2 months and 90 in 3 and scaling. The queue workers aren't meant to be run like that unless you want to keep spawning workers for no reason and hog your memory.

Comment: @Sandeesh I know, I'm rewriting my answer. I was thinking that there is `queue:listen` as before but seems like it's changed

Comment: There is. These are two different commands. `queue:listen - Listen to a given queue` `queue:work - Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon`

Comment: @Sandeesh agree but in 5.4 version there is no `queue:listen`, updated my answer check if it's ok

Comment: There is. I just checked it in my local laravel installation. For some reason they've removed it from the documentation, which is weird.

Comment: @Sandeesh totally agree, I'm not using queue worker just creating my own command and scheduling it. For me it's more mature way than depending on vendor changes that one day removes some feature. They have removed it from docs - seems like they're going to remove it totally.

Comment: Hi num8er, Thanks for the explanation. I now see why is working in 5.1. I have implemented the supervisor like @Sandeesh proposed and it's working